# Can I reset everything to its factory default settings?

Tags: package-management

I have got many problems on my dual-boot ubuntu 11.10. Unity interface always changes from 3D to 2D automatically, when I try to create login password it does not accept my root password, the look of folders always changes automatically,I'm always getting problems with repositories, update manager isn't working, software center doesn't find any internet connection while it actually exists , cannot minimize Google Chrome while I'm working with other applications, and so on.

I actually can't spend several hours on forums to fix that issues because I do not have much time for that. I want somewhat like easy way, by which you can store ALL settings (passwords, unity and so on) to its factory default settings.

Is there such a command or something like that to resolve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can restore gnome-specific settings with the following commands in terminal:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity
```

For details you can see [How to Reset Ubuntu/Gnome Settings to Defaults without Re-installing | Linux FUD](http://linuxfud.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/how-to-reset-ubuntugnome-settings-to-defaults-without-re-installing/)

Additionally you can verify that there are no broken dependencies using:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

And then you can troubleshoot your remaining problems one-by-one.

Comment: nope. didn't worked for me :( Is there any other way ?

Comment: You can actually troubleshoot your every problem one by one, but you have already written that you don't have much time so I think you should consider re-installing your Ubuntu.  (First make backup of your important files). And about stability- Ubuntu is also very stable, you just have to be little careful, get to know first what actually you are doing with your system.

Comment: Okay, I will reinstall it but I don't know how. Could you explain or give a link to a similiar post or page about reinstalling ubuntu 11.10 from dual boot?

Comment: You can actually install Ubuntu inside windows and then later, if u want, can uninstall it. Have a look at it for step-by-step guide:  http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/11/try-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-in-windows-7-without-changing-it/

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I know about Wubi and , frankly, I am actually going to install ubuntu 11.10 in that way next time, cause it's more easy to uninstall. But I do not know how to uninstall my current dual-boot ubuntu 11.10 :(

Comment: To safely remove current Ubuntu installation from dual-boot have a look at this:  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/   you will need your Windows CD/DVD for this. And you should write down 'Restore MBR' section there on a paper because after deleting linux partition you won't be able to boot in windows untill you fix that as mentioned in this guide :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also, please consider editing your responses into your answer so future users don't have to read all of the comments to get the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is to backup important files, insert the installation disc (or usb) then reinstall ubuntu. It will give you the option to wipe/install over the previous version. Then use nepomuk to make a backup after you've got everything installed.Make sure that you only backup things you need like your home folder and try to backup (i think) your ppa list

Answer (score 2):

It is a hard job.
But I have manage to avoid the hard job through an unusal way.

1 , create a new account , for example , mark

```
 adduser mark
```

2 , mv your personal files to home directory of mark's

```
 mv yourfile   /home/mark/
```

3 , change the ownship of your file to mark

```
 chown  -r yourfle   mark
```

3, logout , and then login as mark

4, GNU/LINUX will  allocate mark a new home directory as well as a default system   environment . And everything is ok now.

5 , Be careful , you have to get the root permission to do so .